# Calling a function in a PHP script from the command line

Tags: terminal, command-line-arguments, php

I have a script that has a bunch of different parameterized functions. Is it possible to call any of these functions from the command line and pass in the arguments instead of me having to hard code the function calls in the script?

F.Y.I: I do know how to execute a simple PHP script from the command line

doesn't quite call the function, remember script.php has around 5 different functions and I am looking to call only 1, is that possible

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you cannot do that directly. You have a few options:

- Put every function in a separate php file and call the php file
- use the first argument passed to the php file as the function name, and write a few lines of code to select the correct function.

**Update:**

Here is a example of using the first passed parameter as a function call:

```
if(function_exists( $argv[1] ))
  call_user_func_array($argv[1], $argv);
```

Comment: because it answers the question.

Comment: @artragis it's useless without an example.

Comment: @wes I think artragis and you have interpreted the question differently. It's a bit ambiguous, but I *think* the OP wants to specify the function name itself on the command-line. There is no built-in way of doing this without "having to hard code the function calls in the script".

Comment: yes it answers. @user1020069 wants to call a specific function whose name is given as argument in the script. Your getopt just "parse" the arguments and does not bring the solution that says "use one file per function and then require it and use $function();"

Comment: so, if I pass in these parameters to the script on the command line, what does the script interpret what these arguments are for ?

Comment: That is up to you. You could use the first passed parameter and check if that function exists. I edit my answer with a example.

Comment: @user1020069 The common thread with all these answers is that you're going to have to modify the script, and include some command-line argument parsing to call the appropriate function.  There is no way to do this natively without writing extra code.

Answer (score 4):

`php script.php arg1 arg2` 
access them as $argv[1], $argv[2]...and so on, in your script.

Comment: nice, didn't know about this one.

Comment: FYI, "argv" and "argc" are the traditional names for variables giving access to command-line parameters, for instance in C and Perl.

Answer (score 1):

`getopt()` takes CLI parameters.

```
php /path/to/myscript.php -a foo -b bar -c baz

$arguments = getopt("a:b:c:");

print_r($arguments);

    Array
    (
        [a] => foo
        [b] => bar
        [c] => baz
    )
```

Make it a function `$arguments[a]();` to call `foo();`  you can pass in b also if you have a function arg.

Comment: he wants to call a particular function in script.php, passing args to it, not just run script.php

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you're asking, but the execution would be something like

```
php script.php arg1 arg2 arg3
```

You seem to already know that.  The method for accessing those arguments within the script itself would be to use the variable `$argv`, so `$argv[0]` would be the script, `$argv[1]` would be `"arg1"`, etc.  If that doesn't work, then use `$_SERVER['argv']`.

As for options, you can parse them with [`getopt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php)

Answer (score 1):

You could make the command-line script use its first argument as the function to call, and subsequently the arguments to pass to it. The arguments will appear in the magic array variable `$argv`.

```
// Zero'th "argument" is just the name of your PHP script
$name_of_php_script = array_unshift($argv);
// Next argument will be your callback
$callback = array_unshift($argv);
// Remaining arguments are your parameters
call_user_func_array($callback, $argv);
```

Obviously, you may want to make things more complicated for security, or to pass in special values of some sort, but this does the basic logic you describe in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an option, then pass the function to that eg myscript.php -function my_function

then in your script call the function like

```
$argv[1]()
```