# How to run a php static function from the command line?

Tags: php, command-line

I want to run a function in a php script from the linux command line. The php script looks as follows:

```
<?php
namespace mycompany\admin;
class MyModel
{
    public static function myMethod() {
        echo 'something';
    }
}
```

Normally I would do something like this: `php thefile.php`, but since the function is not called anywhere, it isn't run. I have no idea however, how I could call that function from the command line.

Anybody?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482315/calling-a-function-in-a-php-script-from-the-command-line

this might be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create a file `run.php`:

```
<?php
require 'thefile.php';
MyModel::myMethod();
```

Answer (score 5):

While I would not recommend it, you could call it like this:

`php -r "include('thefile.php');mycompany\admin\MyModel::MyMethod();"`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot run a PHP **method** from command line. You need to call it from a script. You could do this:

```
<?php
namespace mycompany\admin;
class MyModel
{
    public static function myMethod() {
        echo 'something';
    }
}
MyModel::myMethod();
```

and run it from CLI like so:
`php -r myscript.php`